# EmEditorのマクロは、複数スレッドの並列処理でしょうか？

Tags: emeditor

解決済みの報告
江村様のおかけで解決できました。連続置換に変えたことで１０倍速超速くなりました。
１０５万行で約２０分です。おそらくギネス級の速さです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]コアとスレッド数が増えるほど速くなるのかということについてです。
たとえば数十万円のCPUであるThreadripper 3990Xだと、ノートパソコンとかの10倍とか、CPUベンチマークのスコア分だけ速くなるものでしょうか？

私のマクロは、処理数が多いのでEmEditorのマクロでも数十分かかりますが、速ければさらに処理項目を増やしたいのです。
EmEditorの他のテキストエディタよりは断然速いです。
他のテキストエディタだと読み込みすら拒否されて稼働以前の問題だったりします。
全部のテキストエディタは試してませんがEmEditorはマクロでも世界最速かも知れません。
よろしくお願いいたします。

[![画像の説明をここに入力][2]][2]

Comment: 質問の編集は主に「内容の明確化」を行うためのものです。回答を受けた返答などを含めてしまうのは良くない編集ですので、あくまで「質問」の体裁を維持して下さい。

Answer (score 0):

EmEditor のマクロは残念ながらシングル スレッドです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
マルチスレッドに開発される予定はありますでしょうか？
一般的には、そこまでの使い方をする人があまりいないということで、あまり必要ないと言うことで拡張されてないだけなのか、技術的にマルチスレッドは難しい問題があるのでしょうか？
私にとっては現在の使い方も初期段階です。
いずれ、数百万の文字数でもしくは何十万行、百万行の探索をかけるということも拡張で考えています。

Comment: 誤解があるといけないので書くと、マクロ自体はシングル スレッドで実行されますが、マクロの中で実行される様々なコマンドでは、マルチスレッドで実行されています。マクロをマルチ スレッドにするよりも、より多くの方法でマクロ全体を高速化する方法はあります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。そうでしたか。理解致しました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。タスクマネージャーを見ましたところ、EmEditorがマクロで猛烈に探索しているときのCPU使用率は、ほとんどが5％以下、多くて7％以下くらいでした。
これはもっと効率よくなりませんでしょうか？
私がやってますマクロは莫大なパターン探索です。
拡張したいパターンとしては、数百万行になります。現在は、そこまで作れてませんが、これを並列的にCPUの使用率が80％くらいになるまで設定できればかなり良いのですが、技術的には可能なものでしょうか？

Comment: これは、そういう使い方をする人があまりいないので課題になっていなかったのか、課題はありつつ、設定として難しいのか？ということです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: もしよろしければですが、動作検証用の百数十万行のマクロをつくれます。動作の速さを検証するだけのもので、操作として意味のあるものではないですが、私のやりたいことは本質的に同様の動作です。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 検討しますので、よろしければ、マクロやサンプル ファイルなどを zip に圧縮して tech @ emurasoft.com 宛にお送りください。

Comment: ファイルを確かに受け取りました。`Replace`メソッドを使って多くの置換を並べられていますが、このようにすると遅くなります。その代わりに、**連続置換** (`BatchReplace`メソッド) をお使いください。[置換] ダイアログで、[連続] ボタンをクリックすると、ダイアログが拡張して、置換したい文字列の一覧を入力できるようになります。さらに、連続置換の実行をマクロに記録することもできます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。速くできる方法があったとは気がついてませんでした。教えていただき、ありがとうございます。マクロの記録で追加した画像のように動作テストをやってみましたが「終了していない文字列型の定数です。」とかいろんなエラーが出て動作しませんでした。マクロのレコードで保存したマクロそのままでも同様に動きませんでした。原因は何でしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 念のため最新版の 20.5.915 をお使いください。それでも問題が発生する場合は、サンプル ファイルや行いたいことなどを書いてメールしてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。出来ました。100万行超の置換が4時間が10分の1以下の約20分程度まで短縮できました。正規表現も劇的に速くなってます。質問を誤解する人がいるといけないので、質問を更新してこのベンチマーク記録に書き直しておきます。EmEditor Professionalの底力はさすがです。